# How do I access an external hard drive plugged into my router?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd, router

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 and I own a Netgear N600 Wireless Dual Band Router with a USB port built into it.  Naturally, the router came with instructions on how to mount and view this drive with both Windows and Mac, but nothing about Linux.  I have an WD Elements 1 TB external HDD that I would like to plug into the router and share across my home network.  However, when I plug it in, absolutely nothing happens on my desktop.

I checked on two different machines and nothing seems to indicate that the drive has been mounted (or is even seen at all) on either machine.  I am fully aware that it may not be possible to do this with a Linux system, but I was hoping someone might have a suggestion.

Comment: Can you add some commands to your question describing the instructions give to mount the drive under Windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have this same router and just figured out how to access an external drive via Ubuntu.  I wrote [a blog post with the details](http://www.lancebledsoe.com/external-network-drive-ubuntu/) but here's the short version:

1. Install the `smbfs` package (`sudo aptitude install smbfs`).
2. Create a directory in which to mount your external hard drive (e.g., `sudo mkdir /media/public`).
3. Add a line to the file `/etc/fstab` (`gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`) - at the end of the file add this line: `//192.168.1.1/USB_Storage /media/public smbfs guest 0 0`
4. Save your newly updated fstab file then remount your drives (`sudo mount -a`); you should now be able to see your new external drive at `/media/public`.

Comment: I do exactly what you said and I get this error "mount: unknown filesystem type 'smbfs'", to fix it I had to use cifs instead of smbfs

Comment: how would you do this without modifying fstab? I mean, what's the complete mount command?

Answer (score 12):

Do you know your router's IP address? (usually 192.168.1.1, but it may vary).

Open a File Browser (Nautilus) window, then press Ctrl+L and in the location bar that appears type

```
smb://192.168.1.1
```

that *may* give you access to the disk, which is usually published to the network via the SMB protocol.

Comment: This worked for me to connect to the drive, a normal USB SSD connected to a Linksys router, but (X)Ubuntu drops the connection every minute or so. Getting really tired of Ubuntu lately, Why will it not maintain a connection during file transfer from the external drive???

Answer (score 11):

*As of 10/23/2012*
You need CIFS not SAMBA :

1. `sudo apt-get install cifs-utils`
2. Add `//192.168.1.1/USB_Storage /media/public cifs guest 0 0` to your `/etc/fstab`

I would not have gotten this far without the original answer so thank you.

Comment: Thank you this is the correct answer to this question, since cifs replaced smaba !

Answer (score 2):

I have had similar issues with router a year ago. "roadmr" has a great potential solution, but there is a slight chance you might be on 192.168.0.1

in which case you would enter
smb://192.168.0.1    (or other depending on your ip)

...although the most common would be 192.168.1.1 as "roadmr" suggested.

Apologies if you have already tried this, but...
enter the terminal and type `ifconfig`.

---

This will display your IP information

I'm fairly new to Linux, but have worked with networks for a bit, so I just wanted to throw it out there to you that 192.168.1.1 might not be your IP, as I set my router to a more ambiguous IP, or I hide the network altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Good instructions above to make the disk visible, but however, if you want to make it writable for the user, you have to define it with the uid & gid options in your mount command. To find out the uid (numerical User ID) & gid (numerical group ID) of your user, you can use the command:

```
id <user>
```

Then note the values in `uid=` and `gid=` -fields. Once done, you can test it by giving the following command:

```
sudo mount -o nosuid,uid=<insert uid here>,gid=<insert gid here> //192.168.1.1/USB_Storage/ /media/public/
```

If your disk is now writeable, then you can add the same permissions in the fstab entry:

```
//192.168.1.1/USB_Storage/ /media/public/ cifs guest,uid=<insert uid here>,gid=<insert gid here> 0 0
```

EDIT: Confirming that this works on a hard drive plugged with USB into a D-LINK DIR-868L (ubuntu 14.04). Instead of USB_Storage you should use the device's name, which can be found on web GUI of the router (Setup -> Storage ->Device). Dont forget to check the IP address as well (it may not be 192.168.1.1).

Comment: Hello, my home computer has a guest user with no password. If i wanted to exclude that user from seeing my Network drive what should I do? Im using a similar router with 2TB of storage. Should've bought 4TB one :(

Comment: sudo mount -o nosuid,uid=<insert uid here>,gid=<insert gid here> //192.168.1.1/USB_Storage/ /media/public/ won't mount under public but under media

Comment: I don't understand the 'Unable to find suitable address' below:
john@Desktop:~$ sudo mount -o nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000 //192.168.1.1/ExternalHDD/ /media/Public/
Password for root@//192.168.1.1/ExternalHDD/: 
Unable to find suitable address.

Any ideas why?

PS I get this message irrespective of the password that I type.

Answer (score 0):

I used smbfs and after compiled it , you will find mount.smbfs under example script mount.
I am sure you can get that from tar file after you installed binary? I used that command to mount. N600 does not seems to understand cifs.

Comment: In my case USB flash drive patch is visible via smb URL
`smb://192.168.1.1/USB_Drive_Storage_Media`, but can not be opened (inactive).