# HDD on a router

Tags: windows, external-hdd, ftp, lan, router

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I access an external hard drive plugged into my router?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109505/how-do-i-access-an-external-hard-drive-plugged-into-my-router)

I am using ubuntu 12.04LTS.

I am using a D-Link router for our wifi here and we have connected an HDD via usb onto it. I am wondering how can I log myself into it without using the program they are giving for windows... the program is called D-Link shared port plus. I know its IP adress and everything but I don't know what protocol it uses.

Thank you!

Comment: It depends on a model of a router. Could you post it? Most of the time the available protocol is samba, sometimes it's nfs and ftp.

Comment: The router is called DIR-645, but how can I set it up with samba?

Comment: @Takkat But isn't it close enough that this is best handled with new answers to that question? (If we do close this as a duplicate of that question, and you think a bounty is necessary to get new answers, please ping me in chat about it.)

Comment: @Takkat I have been able to access my HDD via smb:// =)

Comment: @JeffLabonte: great! (I envy you for that) - we can then close this as a duplicate.