# mounting network attached hdd( mybook) on ubuntu permission denied

Tags: 14.04, mount, hard-drive, external-hdd, nas

I have tried following the suggestions at [How do I access an external hard drive plugged into my router?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109505/how-do-i-access-an-external-hard-drive-plugged-into-my-router) and tried both the usage of smbfs as suggested by the accepted answer(gave problems with smbfs) and cifs (as suggested by @LEO). which resulted in an error `mount error(13): Permission denied` after `sudo mount -a`.

The hard drive in question is a mybook external hard drive that has recently been formatted to ntfs (received it this way) and is supposed to function both as a NAS and backup disk. It is attached to a DLINK dir885lr router. When connected via USB rather then network Nautilus doesn't have full access to the disk either but I can use the terminal to operate on the disk. Any solution is welcome and I'm fine with formatting the disk however it would be nice if it remains possible to use it to store backups for a windows and linux system as well as serve as a general dumping ground for files to be shared between systems (multiple partitions?)

Comment: what do you do with the terminal to access your hard drive thru usb?

Comment: When I plug it in it gives me acces as it mounts itself in /media/username/diskname. Using the terminal I have permission to do stuff (create folders ext.). However nautiles does not have the same rights (can't create folders).

Comment: mmm apparently nautilus has "read only" access but sudo gives you write access. I think you just need to change the permissions of your files somehow

Comment: by the way try doing `gksudo nautilus` and use the new window and see if you can do what you do with the terminal

Comment: @MinaMichael thing is that the terminal has access without sudo. I would understand this if I was using sudo but I can just give a command like 'mkdir newdir' and a new folder will be created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mount error is being caused by a rejection of the user in general, so it does not mean there is a problem with read / write rights on the disk.

The method explained in the provided link tries to access the shared drive via a guest account, thought some router might allow this by default I think most do not.

For the mentioned router please check via the webpage of the router:

> home>usb device>go to settings>windows file sharing enabled>Allow all users to access

Since the filesystem is translated to CIFS or SMB it will not matter which filesystem you use as long as it is accessible by the router, for this NTFS will be just fine. *(In fact I can not even find if the router will be able to read EXT3 or 4, mostly this means it does not!)*

Regarding your difference between Nautilus and terminal (this is actually a separated question), this appears to have been a bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1021375

and should be solved doing:

Remove `/home/[username]/.config/nautilus` directory and restart or logout and in again.