# Samba/CIFS Mount Error (6)

Tags: networking, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I've tried doing my due diligence and not posting something without putting a bit of research into, but I haven't been able to crack this (rather new to linux).

I'm trying to access files on my External HD which is connected to my Asus router. I've followed all the instructions on this post:

[How do I access an external hard drive plugged into my router?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109505/how-do-i-access-an-external-hard-drive-plugged-into-my-router#205495)

My /etc/fstab looks like:

```
//192.168.29.1/External_HD  /media/public  cifs  guest 0  0
```

However when I run:

```
mount -a
```

I get:

```
mount error(6): No such device or address
```

I know the share is up as I can access it from other computers (Mac & Windows) and I see the directories when I run

```
smbclient -L //192.168.29.1/External_HD -U guest
```

Any ideas on what's wrong in my /etc/fstab?

Comment: If the share is up it should be mounted. You can check with the `findmnt`-command. `/etc/fstab` has more than one line, it could be that another fstab-entry is faulty.

Comment: Thanks I don't see the share when I run `findmnt`. I do see a new option nder Networks for "public" which points to the network share, but when I select it I get the error `Unable to access public: mount: only root can mount //192.168.29.1/External_HD on /media/public`

Comment: Does it help when you add the `user`-option to your fstab-line (see `man fstab`). Or try to mount with `sudo mount -a`

Comment: Unfortunately not, I tried the user option and same result and I'm in a root terminal session vis `sudo -s`

Comment: Does "dmesg" have any hints from the CIFS module about what's happening?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this instead:

```
//NAME_OF_ROUTER/External_HD  /media/public  cifs  guest,ip=192.168.29.1 0  0
```