# Access the USB media that is connected to router

Tags: 16.04, networking, usb-drive, file-sharing

Ubuntu computer connected to the router, that have USB flash drive attached: how to access the USB media from Ubuntu computer? USB flash drive have security permissions already preconfigured for shared folder, router name is visible on Ubuntu under Network > Windows Network > Workgroup > router. But USB drive itself not visible. (Unable to access location/Failed to retrieve share list from server..) Does it require to install a Samba server? Zyxel P-2812HNU-F1 router.

Comment: Every router is different.  Have you tried looking in the manual for your router on how to access attached storage?

Comment: Sure, but manual specifies configuration for Windows system.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/109505/how-do-i-access-an-external-hard-drive-plugged-into-my-router

Comment: In my case USB flash drive patch is visible via smb URL `smb://192.168.1.1/USB_Drive_Storage_Media`, but can't be opened.

Comment: Did you read the second answer where they say to use CIFS instead of smb?

Comment: Yes I read, there was noted that USB drive may be visible via SMB URI (may give access to the disk), not writeable, although. I my case I can't see the drive content, no read access. I haven't installed CIFS yet.